# AuthGuard Error la propiedad no existe

Tags: angular

EStoy intentando implemente un sistema de usuarios, y de rutas por lo que estoy ahora implementando es un guard para restringir el acceso si el usuario no está loggeado, pero me tira varios errores desde la consola del navegador me dice lo siguiente:

> Error: Unexpected value 'AuthGuard' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Y desde la consola de Angular

> ERROR in src/app/auth.guard.ts(13,31): error TS2339: Property 'isLogged' does not exist on type 'LoginService'.

Les dejo mi AuthGuard.guard.ts y mi LoginService

**AuthGuard.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: LoginService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        // If the user is not logged in we'll send them back to the home page
        if (!this.authService.isLogged()) {
            console.log('No estás logueado');
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Y este sería mi **login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  logIn(username:string, password:string) {
    return this.http.post('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
      email: username,
      password: password,     
    });     
  }
}
```

También tengo un **user.service.ts** que es el siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private isUserLoggedIn;
  public usserLogged:User;

  constructor() { 
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  setUserLoggedIn(user:User) {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    this.usserLogged = user;
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log(localStorage);
  }

  getUserLoggedIn() {
    console.log(localStorage);
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }

}
```

Estoy siguien el siguiente tutorial: https://codingpotions.com/angular-seguridad/

Y para el sistema de login: https://codingpotions.com/angular-login-sesion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucioné mi problema, era que estaba llamando al loginService en vez de llamar al UserService

Comment: Puedes borrar tú mismo la pregunta si consideras que no será de utilidad a nadie más o bien publicar los cambios como respuesta y votarla como respuesta correcta. Un saludo.